# Reference SignalR and Noty in every view of a MVC 5 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr-hub, resourcebundle, noty

I'm working on a project in MVC 5 and SignalR to update in real time the views when the SQL Server database changes. My views looks like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<iCare.Models.HttpPop3>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="httpPop3sTable"></div>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts{
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
            var notifications = $.connection.tableHub;

            //debugger;
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            notifications.client.updateHttpPop3s = function () {
                getAllHttpPop3s()

            };
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                alert("connection started")
                getAllHttpPop3s();
            }).fail(function (e) {
                alert(e);
            });
        });


        function getAllHttpPop3s() {
            var tbl = $('#httpPop3sTable');
            $.ajax({
                url: '/httpPop3/GetHttpPop3s',
                contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html'
            }).success(function (result) {
                tbl.empty().append(result);
            }).error(function () {

            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

I'd like to add the SignalR a Noty references for all views with out put these everytime.
So I googled and added the followings code to my project:

BundleConfig.cs

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/noty").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/noty/layouts/",
                        "~/Scripts/noty/themes/",
                        "~/Scripts/noty/jquery.noty.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/SignalR").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js",
                        "~/Scripts/hubs.js"));
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/noty")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/signalr")
```

But when I run a view that uses SignalR it says that can't find the hub and noty's layouts aren't rendered in the page.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found a good solution for SignalR:

In BundleConfig.cs I replaced

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

With

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js",
                    "~/Scripts/hubs.js"));
```

And in _Layout.cshtml

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

And this is /Scripts/hubs.js:

```
(function ($) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/signalr/hubs",
    dataType: "script",
    async: false
});
}(jQuery));
```

I haven't already tried with Noty but I think that will not be different.